# Determining invertibility of weird system

Tags: inverse

Student here, As an academic exercise, is the system
$$y[n] = x[n-1]x[2n]$$
Invertible?

I thought it was since you could find an infinite multiplication series for y[n] that allows you to recover x.

Could someone go over exactly what one to one would mean for a function from X*X->Y?
I have only learned one to one functions in context of functions where an input wasn't repeated.

Comment: hint: you can show whether something is *not* invertible, simply by coming up with an example of where inversion doesn't work. Try a number through which division doesn't help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the following system:
$$x[0]=1 \quad x[2]=1 \quad x[k]=0\text{ for } k\neq0,2$$
Then you have the following output:
$$y[1]=1 \text{ and }\forall k\neq1\quad y[k]=0$$
By remarking that the same output can be produced by the following system :
$$x[0]=-1 \quad x[2]=-1 \quad x[k]=0\text{ for } k\neq0,2$$
you have shown that two different $x$ can give you the same $y$.  This condition indicates that the system is not invertible.